# non-wacom tablet setup Manjaro Linux

Tags: tablet, xorg

I have an Adesso Cybertablet Z7. I did install the Wizardpen driver. I lose pressure sensitivity. I uninstalled it.
I dion't need the Huion drivers either. I only had to do two things.

```
Install xinput_calibrator.
Uninstall something from xorg or xf86.
```

After doing this, the drawing pad worked immediately. No calibration or anything. I have to manually map it to one of my monitors with this:

```
xinput --map-to-output 9 HDMI-0; xinput --map-to-output 13 HDMI-0
```

everytime I use it. I know they change when I restart. I don't mind that.
I just can't remember which file needs to be uninstalled.

```
xinput -- list
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)] 
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ UC-LOGIC Tablet WP5540U Mouse id=9 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ 2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device id=13 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
  ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Power Button id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Sleep Button id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Ideazon Merc Stealth id=10 [slave keyboard (3)]
  ↳ Ideazon Merc Stealth id=11 [slave keyboard (3)]
  ↳ 2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device id=12 [slave keyboard (3)]
  ↳ 2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device id=14 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

Does anyone else have this problem or done what I did to get it to work without calibration or messing with .conf files?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question. I use the Cinnamon DE. What i did was...

1. Make sure Huion and Wizardpen drivers are uninstalled
2. `sudo nemo`.
3. Went to: /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
4. Created a file in there called: 61-UC-LOGIC_Tablet_WP5540U.conf (renamed) I got from [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/tablet-suddenly-stops-working-after-update/18194/28).

In that file I entered:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "UC-LOGIC Tablet WP5540U"
MatchIsTablet "on"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
MatchProduct "Tablet WP5540U"
Driver "evdev"
Option "Mode" "absolute"
EndSection
```

4a. There were other "Options" in there as well that I removed

```
Option "TransformationMatrix" "1 0 0 0 0.75 0 0 0 1"
Option "ConstantDeceleration" "4"
```

I also changed the

```
Option "Module" "relative" to Option "Mode" "absolute"
```

4b. I also changed the Identifier to my model tablet WP5540U.

5. I made sure xf86-input-evdev and libevdev was installed.
6. Then I installed uclogic-tools and xf86-input-synaptics.
7. Rebooted
8. I then typed in terminal

   ```
   xinput --list
   ```

outputting:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ 2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device id=10 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ UC-LOGIC Tablet WP5540U Pen id=13 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ UC-LOGIC Tablet WP5540U Mouse id=14 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button id=8 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ 2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Ideazon Merc Stealth id=11 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ Ideazon Merc Stealth id=12 [slave keyboard (3)]
↳ 2.4G 2.4G Wireless Device id=15 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

As you see the difference from above my device is now recognized and available to map to one of my 4 monitors with:

```
 xinput --map-to-output "id=?" "output"
```

id=? because the id's change on startup.

Pressure sensitivity works flawlessly.

Also. I had no need for calibration.

Comment: libinput xorg xf86 adesso non-wacom wacom manjaro synaptics tablet uclogic uc-logic uclogic-tools evdev